# Restart Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a Backbone View and I want restart it. The view prints a table with prices but when the user push a check, the prices have that change.
I don't know restart my backbone View.

```
GrillaView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
        // events
    },
    initialize : function(){
        // templates
    },
    render : function (){
        this.$el.removeClass('hidden');
        this.renderQuote();
    },
    setCategories : function (collection){
        // Print a template
    },
    addResult : function (item){
        // Print other template
    },
    setPrice : function (prov,item){
        // prices
    },
    filterFuel : function(e){
        // Here I need restart the View
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally unclear question but I assume you want to rerender when new data are available. So when new data are here you'll trigger this.render(); inside your view.

the render function should get its data from a model, when the model is updated you trigger render(). It's that simple. But without more code it's hard to tell what's your problem.

let me know if it helps.